# How do I substring a prefix and suffix from a name field and move them to two new fields?

Tags: sql-server, substring, prefix

If I have a column in my employee table called 'NAME' and it contains text like 'Mr. John Smith Jr.' , how can I search my table to find rows like this, strip out the 'Mr.' and put it in a new column called PREFIX and strip out the 'Jr.' and put it in a new column called SUFFIX? I am in a SQL Server environment. Is there a way to actually take the Data from the one field and move it to another, or can I just find the 'Mr.' And 'Jr.' and identify them in the results?

Comment: Did you try anything dear friend??

Comment: How do you tell the difference between a prefix/suffix and a name that doesn't fit a pattern your code assumes?

Comment: You can write a trigger which will parse and insert the result data into three columns.

Comment: I am fairly new to this and didn't know what to try. I tried a trim and a substring, but only identified the  'Mr.' - it didn't move it into a new field called prefix, nor did it remove it from the field called EmployeeName. We won't be able to tell the difference on every prefix/suffix that doesn't fir the pattern, but as we data cleanse, we will narrow it down. How would I write the trigger suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can just add a new col. into your table. Then use the update query like this:-

```
select substring('Mr. John Smith Jr.',1, charindex(' ' ,'Mr. John Smith Jr.'));
```

This will give you the first word "MR." and then use this query:-

```
select reverse(rtrim(substring(reverse('Mr. John Smith Jr.'), 1, charindex(' ', reverse('Mr. John Smith Jr.')))));
```

This will give you the last word i.e. "JR." and update your table with this.

Comment: This works GREAT! Thanks for the help. One more question So when I parse out the 'Mr.' and the 'Jr.' into PREFIX and SUFFIX, how can I now create a new name field that will contain just what's left - 'John Smith'?

Answer (score 0):

Use this query to achieve your desirables:-

```
SELECT REVERSE(
               SUBSTRING(
                         REVERSE(
                                 SUBSTRING('Mr. John Smith Jr.', CHARINDEX(' ' ,'Mr. John Smith Jr.'), LEN('Mr. John Smith Jr.'))
                                ), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE('Mr. John Smith Jr.')),LEN(REVERSE('Mr. John Smith Jr.'))
                        )
              );
```

Comment: The above query will give you only "JOHN SMITH".

Comment: I tried that, but as I'm not actually using the string 'Mr. John Smith Jr.' but rather whatever is the in the field EMPLOYEE_NAME, it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you plz share that where the real prob is??